# How can I turn off "MD024/no-duplicate-heading/no-duplicate-header: Multiple headings with the same content" error in Markdown file?

Tags: markdown, static-analysis

I have several sections with the same name but inside different parent sections:

```
# Page title

## Section A

### Examples

## Section B

### Examples
```

[markdownlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint) linter gives me this warning:

> MD024/no-duplicate-heading/no-duplicate-header: Multiple headings with the same content.

https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/md024.md

How can I turn off this warning and still be warned when I have several sections with the same name on the same level, like so:

```
# Page title

## Section A

## Section A
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Create `.markdownlint.json` file in the root folder and add this JSON:

```json
{
  "no-duplicate-heading": {
    "siblings_only": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed in a more recent version of [markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint-cli2/blob/82c791e94c2e2ab2119437d61c722c8e0c20d6c9/schema/markdownlint-config-schema.json#L607C1-L608C1). The alias for `heading` called `header` was removed and the parameter changed.

```json
  "no-duplicate-heading": {
    "siblings_only": true
  },
```